# How-to catch "log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger"?

Tags: java, log4j

I want to handle this error to set up an alternative configuration log4j. Is that possible?

I don't have any stacktrace, only log's warnings

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (agent.Test1Agent.JavaAgent). 
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. 
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: Can you share your stack trace?

Comment: Please, consider adding the error messages into question itself instead of putting them into comment(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want correctly because log4j doesn't throw any exceptions or notifies somehow in case of misconfiguration. But it is possible.

See PoC below

```
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.Configurator;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class Log4jAlternativeConfig {

    private static class PrintStreamCallbackSupportDecorator extends PrintStream {

        public PrintStreamCallbackSupportDecorator(OutputStream out, Callback callback) {
            super(out);
            this.callback = callback;
        }

        public interface Callback {
            public void onPrintln(String x);
        }

        private Callback callback;

        @Override
        public void println(String x) {
            callback.onPrintln(x);
            super.println(x);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PrintStreamCallbackSupportDecorator.Callback callback = new PrintStreamCallbackSupportDecorator.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onPrintln(String x) {
                if (x.startsWith("log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger")) {
                    Configurator configurator = new PropertyConfigurator();
                    URL url = Loader.getResource("log4j_alternative.properties");
                    configurator.doConfigure(url, LogManager.getLoggerRepository());
                }
            }
        };

        System.setErr(new PrintStreamCallbackSupportDecorator(System.err, callback));

        Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Log4jAlternativeConfig.class);

        //causes "No appenders could be found for logger" warning
        log.error("test");

        //should be logged as configured in log4j_alternative.properties
        log.error("test 2");
    }
}
```

The solution isn't perfect but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an alternative log4j configuration by providing a default configuration file on your classpath. Since log4j uses `Thread.getContextClassLoader().getResource()` to locate the default configuration files and does not directly check the file system, it should be included in your jar. So that if no external configuration provided it will fall back on the default configuration.
See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info